# Display a text in site collection's page from a document

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection

If you have a word document containing a text that is "My captain oh captain". The document is located at a list inside a site collection. I wonder if it possible to take  the text "My captain oh captain" from the document's content and display it a the index page of site collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can use the Client Object Model with JQuery to get the contents of the document. But I recommend that the text is in a txt.